# Is this image a direct sum of two Moebius bands?

Tags: mobius-band

[image]

If we just look at the exterior surface of this, and view it as a 2-manifold, is this the direct sum of two Mobius bands? I see that this object has 2 sides and is orientable. If we view it as a 3-manifold, is that what makes it a direct sum of two Mobius bands, since we have $S^1\times \mathbb{R}^2$ in some way?

If I try to consider Euler characteristics, I get 11*\chi(cube). I think that’s just the statement that the cubes don’t give a triangulation of M x M, so we don’t get \chi(M x M) = \chi(M)•\chi(M)=0•0=0 for M a Moebius band. However, shouldn’t we still be able to view the cubes as gluing together to give a CW complex?

Comment: It seems that both bands you mention each have two half twists...

Comment: Okay, then: what is it?

Comment: It appears to be a torus, $S^1 \times S^1$, with two copies of the (2,1) [torus knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus_knot) as boundaries of the two strips (annuli, $S^1 \times [0,1]$).